# Retrofit+RxJava: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not locate call adapter for f.e<b.v>

Tags: android, retrofit, proguard

I have a serious problem with Retrofit+rx and ProGuard.

1. App works in debug
2. App works in release with minifyEnabled false
3. App works in release with minifyEnabled true and useProguard
   false
4. App doesn't work in release with minifyEnabled= true

This code is how to create the Retrofit:

```
@Provides @Singleton Retrofit provideRetrofit(Call.Factory factory, Environment environment) { //A Gson formatter to covert string in date Gson gson = new GsonBuilder() .setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ") .create(); return new Retrofit.Builder() .baseUrl(environment.getBaseUrl()) .callFactory(factory) .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson)) .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create()) .build(); }
```

Here is is my ProGuard:

http://pastebin.com/696myxMM

It's confusing, sorry, but I tried every solution.

I have this exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.xxxx.xxxx/com.xxx.xxx.android.entrance.EnterActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to create call adapter for f.e<b.v> for method d.a at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416) at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to create call adapter for f.e<b.v> for method d.a at e.l$a.a(ServiceMethod.java:720) at e.l$a.b(ServiceMethod.java:234) at e.l$a.a(ServiceMethod.java:160) at e.k.a(Retrofit.java:166) at e.k$1.invoke(Retrofit.java:145) at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.invoke(Proxy.java:393) at $Proxy1.a(Unknown Source) at com.xxx.xxx.network.b.a.b.a(EnterApiImpl.java:37) at com.xxxx.xxx.network.b.a.d.a(EnterInteractorImpl.java:32) at com.xxx.xxxxx.android.entrance.d.a(EnterPresenterImpl.java:71) at com.xxxx.xxxx.android.entrance.d.a(EnterPresenterImpl.java:56) at com.xxxx.xxx.android.entrance.EnterActivity.onCreate(EnterActivity.java:45) at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6251) at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) ... 9 more Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not locate call adapter for f.e<b.v>. Tried: * com.d.a.a.a.f
```